# set up inbound routing LAN-LAN on Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows, routing, vmware-workstation

I have a problem I thought I will find a lot of answers for, but at the end it seems that somehow this topic is nowhere covered. Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a Mac running VMWare Fusion, and in this VMW environment I installed and started several machines. They all are in VMW defined with host only NIC, which means that they "live" in a separated network environment (192.168.0.0). My Mac is in net 192.168.1.0

What I wanted is to setup one virtual Machine as a router between two networks so that the virtual machines can go "out" and my Mac can go "in", because I want to ssh into some of the virtual Linuxes.

So I took one Windows2003, added another NIC to it, set that new NIC into the 192.168.1.0 net with IP 192.168.1.59 and ran the "routing and remote access" setup, and managed to make the "way out" work, so all the machines from the virtual env can use this router Machine as a gateway to the 192.168.1.0 net and on.

On my mac I added a new route with "route add" and set for net 192.168.0.0 the gateway address to the second NIC of the Windows2003 (192.168.1.59). And when I ping something on the 192.168.0.0 I see the 192.168.1.59 NIC receiving the packets, but these do not get forwarded to NIC 192.168.0.1, so I guess the inbound routing is not active. Can somebody point me to an article which would explain me how to activate it? I found many RAS and VPN article, with dial up lines and such, but nothing for simple LAN-LAN routing.

Answer (score 0):

Host only networking means just what it says: The guest OS can only communicate with the host. To achieve what you want to do you will need to use bridged mode.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I do not want to expose these machines to the public net because then I could run into IP conflicts. It is only me needing these machines and this is why I keep them ""behind the door", and as said they communicate with each other just fine. I'm not sure if I can achieve that in any other way.